# Docker compose volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

While searching for a docker-compose file I came across this. I saw that the volumes having 2 instructions I'm pretty sure that 2nd one is mapping but I don't know what's the 1st one.

```
 volumes:
  - /app/node_modules
  - ./server:/app
```

I

Comment: The linked question has some details on this.  Remember that a volume like this takes precedence over both the bind mount and the content in the image, and tells Docker the directory is important user data that must not be updated; so the first line is (among other things) an instruction to Docker to ignore all changes to the application's `package.json`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docker-compose reference on [volumes short-syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3) the first format you mentioned `- /app/node_modules` follows the format `SOURCE:]TARGET[:MODE]`, where you are only providing the `TARGET` (the path in the container).

When the source is omitted, [an anonymous volume is created](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag), meaning the Docker volume will be created for you with a random name. Basically, a volume in the Docker filesystem will be created and mounted to your container at the path `/app/node_modules`. This is useful if you want to later re-mount and share data between containers like in [this example in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#share-data-among-machines).

You can read more about Docker volumes here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/